# mysql-connector-python-2.0.2-py3.3.msi Installation failed

Tags: python, mysql

I want to use "import MySQLdb" 
So I downloaded Windows (Architecture Independent), MSI Installer Python 3.3
Address ：http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
After the installation is complete,tell me installation failed

> > > import MySQLdb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
> > >       Please tell me how to do。thx.

PS:I use MySQL Server 5.5 and python33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at any example in the documentation and you will find that the module coming with oracle's mysql connector is not named `MySQLdb`, but simply `mysql` (or rather `mysql.connector`):

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', password='tiger',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='employees')
cnx.close()
```

From:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html